# Cell box name where condition is true, data location with Google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi everyone I have a table, this table is from  a survey so basically I'm checking the data quality, there is a few conditions that I want to check for example if there is value bigger than 1000, if that's the case I want to know what cell is containing that data, I know that I can use conditional formating in Google sheets but I want to create some kind of report, this is my data:

[image]

One example of what I want is locate the Don't knows the first Don't know is located in E3 so my desirable output will be that is displayed the E3 where I found E3 for that row. [this is my document in Google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10InK3OQSZHMIvjXwRaOyAJJJZDL8TsiBNLIPHGVTiF8/edit?usp=sharing)  you can find more details about the data and desirable outpus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have some options. Basically it filters the cells with MATCH. With ADDRESS find the cells, and joins them with TEXTJOIN:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",1,
INDEX(IFNA(ADDRESS(ROW(a)-1,
 FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!1:1)),INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1)="Don’t know"),4))))))

=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",1,
  INDEX(IFNA(ADDRESS(ROW(a)-1,
  FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!1:1)),VALUE(INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1))>1000),4))))))

=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",1,INDEX(IFNA(ADDRESS(ROW(a)-1,FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!1:1)),ISBLANK(INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1)),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!1:1))<=MAX(XMATCH("*",INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1),2,-1),XMATCH(1,INDEX(IFERROR(INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1)/INDIRECT("data!"&ROW(a)-1&":"&ROW(a)-1))),0,-1))),4))))))
```

[image]

Comment: The last one didn't worked I think is because it has a 11 cells

Comment: What is it that didn't work?

Comment: The last formula, the one for the empty spaces

Comment: If you're meaning J11,K11 it's part of "Bigger than 1000 cells"

Comment: Now is ready and actually I don't want to use the table that I used

Comment: Hi Martin I need help I just what to use the formula in a range of cells BH2-BL21 could you help me modifing the formula I tried but it give's me error

Comment: Martin help please